# HTTP 503 ao executar o snippet

Tags: bug

A execução do snippet do site está retornando HTTP 503.

```html
<h1>Spoiler alert!</h1>
<p>Você não verá essa mensagem (ou vai, não acontece para todos ¯\_(ツ)_/¯)</p>
```

O retorno é sempre:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema parece estar no domínio https://stacksnippets.net.

Comment: Já tem no metão?

Comment: @Maniero Agora tem: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/376431/1452488

Comment: E, inclusive, já parou o problema. Snippets funcionando normalmente aqui.

Comment: Tive exatamente o mesmo problema, mas no dia a seguir parou logo. Curiosamente não acontecia com todos os usuários.

Comment: Só para constar, como deve saber (é claro que sabe, falamos muito disso xD), o 503 é resposta de serviço em manutenção, então geralmente é isso mesmo, desligaram para efetuar alguma manutenção, não é como os outros status `5xx`, então provavelmente é só esperar mesmo :)